# Twitter's Bootstrap popover not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using the popover plugin from Bootstrap. ([link](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#twipsy)) but it's not working.

HTML:

```
<a data-placement='above' class='danger' rel='popover' data-content='test code here' href='#'>Click</a>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../js/twipsy.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="../js/popover.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is add the following script code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("a[rel=popover]")
            .popover({
                offset: 10
            })
            .click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
            })
    })
</script>
```

This way, all the **a** elements with the attribute **rel="popover"** will get this popover to appear.

No more changes are needed to your code and it works great... at least on my machine, of course ;-)
Try it out!

Comment: Sorry, i've misread your question. You want the popover, not the twipsy tooltip, I'll change my answer in 1 minute.