# My Bootstrap popover is not working, how can I debug it?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, import, popover

I have already see following answers:

1) [Twitter's Bootstrap popover not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871073/twitters-bootstrap-popover-not-working)

2) [Twitter bootstrap .popover not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985788/twitter-bootstrap-popover-not-working)

3) [Bootstrap Popover not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845876/bootstrap-popover-not-working)

None helps me solve the problem.

I am trying to use a Popover in Bootstrap, I click the button but the popover doesn't appear.

I can not find the problem. This is the HTML code of the popover and I got it from the documentation.

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
            Popover on top
        </button>
```

This is instead the code relating to imports.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/global.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/lightslider/dist/css/lightslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/flags/flags.css"/>
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/script/index.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/popper.js/dist/popper.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/lightslider/dist/js/lightslider.js"></script>
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap and jQuery are you using? Does your developer console indicate any errors related to resource loading or conflicts?  Have you included the JS necessary to enable popovers (It is an 'opt in' component of Bootstrap, not on by default).

Comment: I added `popper.js` (question updated). The versions are whom `bower` gives to me. After import `popper.js` I noticed two new errors: `SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'export'`in popper.js line 2371 and `TypeError: Bootstrap tooltips require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)` in jquery.min.js line 31048. I do not understand why there are these two errors, also I have not touched the sources just downloaded with bower.

Comment: We really need more details... since Bootstrap dropped official Bower support we don't know what versions of jQuery, Popper, or Bootstrap are being included.  But it sounds like your Popper.js asset has an error that causes it not to load properly, which is causing a cascade effect resulting in errors w/ Bootstrap since it cannot use Popper for positioning.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that **bootstrap** had abandoned **bower**. Thanks to your advice, I have deleted the packages downloaded with **bower** and have re-downloaded them using **npm**. Now everything works very well. You can answer my question, so you vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments - the likely culprit here is Bower.  Bootstrap abandoned Bower in V4 in favor of Yarn or npm:

> Dropped Bower support as the package manager has been deprecated for
>   alternatives (e.g., Yarn or npm). See **bower/bower#2298** for details.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#breaking

Relying on a different package manager or including Bootstrap manually is the best route to ensuring that all of your CSS and JavaScript (as it relates back to Bootstrap) complies with V4 requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the instance of popover... try adding

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});
```

and verify that your links are correct.
Also verify its requirements [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/)

Comment: I added it into `$(document).ready(function () { $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); ... });` but still not working.

Comment: which bootstrap version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following changes and try again.

Include the css files in the head section and JS file before ''.

Also add the below js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});
```

The main issue is in the css confliction:

Replace your button with this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default povr" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on top
</button>
```

and add this css

```
.povr{ margin-top:50px;}
```

This will fix the issue. Change the CSS according to your need.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzazvfbm/9/)

Comment: I made the changes you suggest. Moreover I imported `popper.js` before including `bootstrap.js`. But still not working. Do you think that if you post the website link, it can be of more help to you?

Comment: I just added js fiddle link, please check it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I checked to see if it works, as shown in the link. However, there is something conflicting about my project and I am trying to figure out what, but I'm not finding the bug.

Comment: Is there any reason there are two document readies nested in each other in the 1st code sample?

Comment: hmm since u are already in the .ready function isn't it redundant to use `function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});`